# Method or algorithm for finding rational approximation to real

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, rational-numbers

I'm looking for an method for finding a small rational number within some *specified* tolerance of a given number, possibly real.

By way of illustration, a solution to the problem of finding a rational approximation to $\pi$, accurate to within $0.001$, is $\frac{201}{64}$. Similarly, $\frac{82}{45}$ is a solution to finding a rational approximation of $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3}$, accurate to within $\frac{1}{2048}$.

The Mathematica software provides a function `Rationalize[]` which gives solutions to similar problems, but I'm looking for an explanation, or even more usefully, a published description, of a suitable algorithm.

Comment: The topic you'll want to learn about is "continued fractions".

Comment: And most every intro Number Theory textbook will cover that topic, not to mention a few thousand websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed all about continued fractions.

A good place to start is indeed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

But it is useful to have an illustration so as to get an idea of the principle behind it all. Let’s look for approximations to π

π = 3 + 0.141592653589793

so, approximating that number:
0.141592653589793 = 1/ 7.062513305931046

7.062513305931046 = 7 + 0.062513305931046

so, approximating that number:
0.062513305931046 = 1/ 15.99659440668572

Unwinding that calculation with decimals:

- 16
- Invert = 0.0625
- Add 7 = 7.0625
- Invert = 0.141592920353982
- Add 3 = 3.141592920353982

…which is a pretty good approximation.

Unwinding again, but this time with fractions:

- 16
- Invert = 1/16
- Add 7 = 113/16
- Invert = 16/113
- Add 3 = 355/113

…and 355/113 is indeed the “best possible” approximation with numerator and denominator of that sort of size. Similarly if you stopped the calculation one step earlier you’d get 22/7, which is “best possible” of *that* size. And one step earlier is 3/1, again best possible.

With more ingenuity you can construct the approximating fractions as you go along, rather than (as I did) first going forwards and then constructing the fractions by going backwards.